# How do I invoke a controller action on node click of Telerik MVC Treeview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

How to invoke a controller action on selecting or on click the node of Telerik MVC treeview?

```
<%
= Html.Telerik().TreeView()
            .Name("TreeView1")
            .ClientEvents(events => events
                        .OnSelect("onSelect")
                    )
            .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
            {
                mappings.For<Models.Samples>(binding => binding
                        .ItemDataBound((item, mno) =>
                        {
                            item.Text = mno.A;
                            item.Value = mno.B;
                        }));                     
            })            
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it call your controller action by clicking on node

```
<%
= Html.Telerik().TreeView()
            .Name("TreeView1")
            .ClientEvents(events => events
                        .OnSelect("onSelect")
                    )
            .BindTo(Model, mappings =>
            {
                mappings.For<Models.Samples>(binding => binding
                        .ItemDataBound((item, mno) =>
                        {
                            item.Text = mno.A;
                            item.Value = mno.B;
                        }));                     
            })            
%>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSelect(e) {
        window.location = "/Controller/Action"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: is that the only way? call from client function?

Comment: yes this is only way you can call action for more information please refer link http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/events.html